# HelpBar Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a relatively trivial question, and I'm sorry to ask it.  However, I am trying to do work in Oracle SQL Developer, and I can't figure out how to bring up the helpbar on the left-hand side that shows all of my objects.

How can I pull it up?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm picturing in my head what you are saying properly, there are two ways:

1. Click the Window menu item and then "Reset Windows to Factory Settings" which shows the Connections and Reports items along the left hand side.

Or

1. Click the View menu item and select "Connections" (or maybe "Recent Objects" if that's what you're after.)